# PHP: How to spread an array as function parameters

Tags: php, static-methods

I'm trying to use `__callStatic` to wrap the calls to differents static functions in my class.

This current version of the code allows me to do so with functions that have 0 or 1 parameter:

```php
class test {

  public static function __callStatic($name, $args) {
    if (method_exists(__CLASS__, $name)) {
      echo "it does exist\n";
      return forward_static_call([__CLASS__, $name], $args[0]);
    } else {
      echo "it does not exist\n";
    }
  }

  private static function mfunc($param1, $param2) {
    echo "that's my func \n";
    echo "$param1\n";
    echo "$param2\n";
  }

}
test::notafunc("one", 'two');
test::mfunc("one", "two");
```

However it will fail for `mfunc` since it has two parameters.
How can i spread the different arguments when i'm calling the function ?

I can't use the new [spread operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array) because I am locked on PHP 7.2.
I can't modify `mfunc` either, because I have way too much methods to change in the project.

Comment: The old way was `call_user_func_array()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spread operator is still usable in PHP 7.2, what you point to is something slightly different (it's about being able to use it as part of an array).  So you can use

```
return forward_static_call([__CLASS__, $name], ...$args);
```

As a more legible version...

```
return static::{$name}(...$args);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I was trying to do